# Concatenating two text files in Python

Tags: python, file, concatenation

I am very beginner Python. So my question could be quite naive.
I just started to study this language principally due to mathematical tools such as Numpy and Matplotlib which seem to be very useful.

In fact I don't see how python works in fields other than maths
I wonder if it is possible (and if yes, how?) to use Python for problems such as text files treatment.

And more precisely is it possible to solve such problem:

I have two files A.txt and B.txt . The  A.txt file contains three columns of numbers and looks like this

```
 0.22222000  0.11111000  0.00000000   
 0.22222000  0.44444000  0.00000000   
 0.22222000  0.77778000  0.00000000   
 0.55556000  0.11111000  0.00000000   
 0.55556000  0.44444000  0.00000000   
.....
```

The  B.txt file contains three columns of letters F or T  and looks like this :

```
  F   F   F   
  F   F   F   
  F   F   F   
  F   F   F   
  T   T   F   
......
```

The number of lines is the same in files A.txt and B.txt

I need to create a file  which would look like this

```
   0.22222000  0.11111000  0.00000000   F   F   F   
   0.22222000  0.44444000  0.00000000   F   F   F   
   0.22222000  0.77778000  0.00000000   F   F   F   
   0.55556000  0.11111000  0.00000000   F   F   F  
   0.55556000  0.44444000  0.00000000   T   T   F
```

.......

In other words I need to create a file containing 3 columns of A.txt and then the 3 columns of B.txt file.

Could someone help me to write the lines in python needed for this?

I could easily do it in fortran but have heard that the script in python would be much smaller.
And since I started to study math tools in Python I wish also to extend my knowledge to other opportunities that this language offers.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course Python can be used for text processing (possibly it is even better suited for that than for numerical jobs). The task in question, however, can be done with a single Unix command: `paste A.txt B.txt > output.txt`

And here is a Python solution without using `numpy`:

```
 with open('A.txt') as a:
     with open('B.txt') as b:
         with open('output.txt', 'w') as c:
             for line_a, line_b in zip(a, b):
                 c.write(line_a.rstrip() + ' ' + line_b)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to concatenate them the good ol' fashioned way, and put them in a new file, you can do this:

```
a = open('A.txt')
b = open('B.txt')
c = open('C.txt', 'w')
for a_line, b_line in zip(a, b):
    c.write(a_line.rstrip() + ' ' + b_line)

a.close()
b.close()
c.close()
```

Comment: rstripping a_line is probably needed

Comment: Okay, now I got why from your other comment. Thanks.

Comment: I tried this

but obtained an eroor message


  File "<stdin>", line 3
    for f in [a, b, c]:
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Line 3? Seems like you're doing something wrong here. I've tried this on my system and it does indeed work.

Comment: Well it may depend on system. I will see more precisely later.

Comment: The message appeared after this for f in [a, b, c]:

Comment: I copied it, another problem appeared

Comment: >>> for a_line, b_line in zip(a, b):
...     c.write(a_line.rstrip() + ' ' + b_line)
... a.close(), b.close(), c.close()
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    a.close(), b.close(), c.close()
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>

Comment: Yeah, this sort of thing happens when you copy code directly into python shell. Try it now!

Comment: Cheers. 
You should consider marking the answer that was most helpful to you. There are 2 other excellent answers here in addition to my basic one, so accept the solution that helped you the most. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,read files as numpy arrays

```
 a = np.loadtxt('a.txt')
b = np.genfromtxt('b.txt',dtype='str')
```

In case of b you need genfromtext because of string content.Than

```
np.concatenate((a, b), axis=1)
```

Finally, you will get

```
np.concatenate((a, b), axis=1)
array([['0.22222', '0.11111', '0.0', 'F', 'F', 'F'],
       ['0.22222', '0.44444', '0.0', 'F', 'F', 'F'],
       ['0.22222', '0.77778', '0.0', 'F', 'F', 'F'],
       ['0.55556', '0.11111', '0.0', 'F', 'F', 'F'],
       ['0.55556', '0.44444', '0.0', 'T', 'T', 'F']], 
      dtype='<U32')
```

Comment: Thanks. I have one more question.

Comment: How do I write the obtained array to a file?
I tried this

c=np.concatenate((a, b), axis=1)

np.savetxt('test.txt', c)

But I got following error message

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1073, in savetxt
    fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))
TypeError: float argument required, not numpy.string_

Comment: This concatenate produces an array of strings (U32). `savetxt` then requires a string compatible `fmt`, e.g. `%s`.

Comment: It is possible to make an array with mixed float and string (or boolean) fields but that's more complicated, and writing it with `savetxt` requires a fancier `fmt`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It works now. I got one more problem. But it's solved now. In fact after concatenation the numbers in the resulting array contained only one digit.

Comment: To solve it before concatenation I changed the format of array a to string of length 15 (7 was enough). The final sequence of commands  looked like this

Comment: a = np.loadtxt('A.txt')
b = np.genfromtxt('B.txt',dtype='str')
aa=a.astype('|S15')
c=np.concatenate((aa, b), axis=1)
np.savetxt('output.txt',c,fmt="%s")

Comment: a = np.loadtxt('A.txt');
b = np.genfromtxt('B.txt',dtype='str');
aa=a.astype('|S15');
c=np.concatenate((aa, b), axis=1);
np.savetxt('output.txt',c,fmt="%s")